# How to customize the xmlsitemap?

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I installed the [xmlsitemap](http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module and would like to customize the sitemap.

For example, I would like to exclude some nodes that have a certain term reference field.
I would also like to be able to create separate sitemaps for each content type.

Is there a way to do that? 
Otherwise I could probably generate the xml sitemaps with [service_views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views) module.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: I just used the xmlsitemap module

Comment: What do you mean with, "some nodes that have a certain term reference field"?

Comment: for example, I want to exclude all nodes that have a tag (term reference) value of "jokes". I tried creating an XML sitemap with views but couldn't get the XML formatted correctly. In views it would be easy to do the inclusions/exclusions ...

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same with [xmlsitemap](http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) modules

Enable XML sitemap node, XML sitemap taxonomy submodules.

[image]

After that you will get these options.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_xmlsitemap_link_alter:

```
function hook_xmlsitemap_link_alter(array &$link, array $context) {
  $nid = $link['loc'];
  if ($nid == 'node/[:id]') {
    $link['status'] = 0;
    $link['access'] = 0;
  }
  }
}
```